# Redirect data from one device to another device

Tags: automation, iot, node-red, thingsboard

The title may be hard to understand, so I will give an overview picture of what the situation is.

We have many data loggers which all send data to thingsboard.
These dataloggers are programmed in Node-Red.
One datalogger is used between two machines.
Each machine has their own device on thingsboard.

The first issue we encountered was Node-Red wasn't allowing us to have multiple MQTT connections open at a single time. To fix this we added a loggerId field to the JSON message.
Now thingsboard gets the data from both machines but under the one device.

So to solve this we want to make a 'parent' device that all the data loggers send their data to. This parent device will have a rule chain that will read what the loggerId is from the JSON message, then it will redirect the JSON message to the appropriate device where it will be stored, manipulated, etc.

I hope this makes sense, I'm not the best at putting my thoughts into words...

This is a rough flowchart of what needs to happen.

[image: Flowchart]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There isn't a question here. At best there might be a list of requirements, but no attempt to solve the problem. StackOverflow doesn't work that way, you need to show us what you tried and explain how it doesn't work then we may be able to help you fix it.

Comment: Also Node-RED can happily support multiple MQTT connections to 1 or many MQTT brokers, before trying to build a complex multi levelled solution you may do better looking at the original "problem" again.

Comment: The issue isn't with Node-RED, the issue is with the device that it is running on. When I create multiple MQTT-OUT connections one connects and the other gets stuck on connecting and doesn't change state, if one disconnects the other connects. I don't really know how to put it into a question besides, is there a way in thingsboard rule chains to redirect data from one device to another device. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can help you solve the problem. You can carry the ID of the child device in the data uploaded by the parent device, and then send the message to the rule chain through the parent device. Use the rule node change originator to switch the initiator. The node needs to select Entity, so that the device ID in the message can be dynamically canceled, and then the device can be dynamically switched, so that the message can be sent to the corresponding child device。

Comment: There was another question here but I answered it, I was just being very dumb and forgot to add the save data nodes.... Thanks very much for your help!!